# Clarification on a failed audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/5254165) which linked to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24275626/dummy-html-attribute). I thought it was actually a reasonable question, so wanted to get some feedback so I'm not causing more problems. :)

Comment: Yeah, I agree that the question does not really seem to be too broad. Sometimes the audits are just disputable. Take it like a man, you won't die if you get a temporary ban ;)

Comment: Upvoted and voted to reopen. OP was on the right track and simply didn't know about the existence of data attributes.

Comment: When did you vote to leave open? If it was between June 18th and 3 hours ago, then you would have failed it. Unfortunately, the review audit system does not know whether the original decision was correct, just that is what 5 people decided. So when it plays it back to you, it assumes you would take the same action if the system had worked as it was intended. In my opinion, the review audit should not put items on the queue that are pending reopen. Too much ambiguity.

Comment: @staticx As far as I understand, a single vote *not* to close is enough to prevent the question from being used for audits. However, in this case, the votes to reopen came as an indirect result of the failed audit, so that's too late.

Comment: @hvd: Understood. I would imagine there is a 1 percent chance it is wrong. Unfortunately, 5 people screwed it up for the next person.

Comment: I think audit candidates should gather more votes than needed for closing to be considered as audits to reduce such incidents.

Comment: a lot of audits are highly questionable. And even when not, just trying to leave a comment on the post in question can make you fail the audit, even if the comment you were going to leave had nothing to do with why the audit would supposedly fail.